# How to get the text of the last few sentences from non tagged text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a simply solution to a simply problem. 
I get an html text and I need to remove the three last sentences and put that sentences in other box, all on client side.

My html hasn't tags inside, it's a plain text.

I try different ways, building an "Array", but i'm sure it's possible something easier.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

```
var t = $("#text-generic p").text();
var sentences = t.split('.');
sentences.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
});
```

I separate the sentences in an Array called sentences, but... How can I get the last 4 sentences, for example, Remove them from the html and write in other side? It's possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a regular expression. Show what you have tried.

Comment: Is there any `carriage return` or something which tells a new sentence has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **slice()**, here is a fairly simple JS solution:

```
var t= "Per aliquip accusamus ad. eleifend repudiare adversarium sed id. Ne mel audire nominavi verterem. Ei per munere suscipit abhorreant, iisque docendi definiebas usu no, vim assum meliore voluptatum ad. Accusam facilisis per ex. ius ea summo viris quaerendum. Qui ei erat aliquam, est an habemus nominavi pertinacia. Scaevola consectetuer ex vix, ferri antiopam eam ut."
var sentences=t.split('.');
sentences.slice(0,-3) // change -3 to the number of sentences to truncate with -ive sign
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/8j21uv9y/)

Comment: I am glad it worked out for you. Good luck and welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `splice()` to do this:

```
var arraySentences = $('#first').html().split('.');
var numberOfSentences = arraySentences.length - 1; // because of blank after last period
var numberOfSentencesWeWantInSecond = 4;
var remainderOfSentences = numberOfSentences - numberOfSentencesWeWantInSecond;
var membersOfFirst = arraySentences.splice(0, remainderOfSentences);
$('#first').html(membersOfFirst.join('. '));
$('#second').html(arraySentences.join('. ')); // the leftover sentences
```

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/rzgpu11w/